# Sandbox verify account?

Tags: paypal, sandbox, verify

I have created an business account through sandbox.paypal.com.  I'm currently trying to verify it so that I can accept payments, but it's refusing to accept any bank accounts I enter.  I've also tried to create accounts through the developer portal, but those keep throwing an error and telling me to try again no matter what I do.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PayPal will recommend you to create a sandbox account from [developer portal](https://developer.paypal.com), I am able to create sandbox account from my [developer portal](https://developer.paypal.com). Please try to use different web browsers by removing cookies and cache. If you are still receiving an error from developer portal. Then file an MTS ticket at [PayPal MTS portal](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/) with the error message screenshot, error page source code. Then you will get an assistance from PayPal MTS engineers directly. You may provide the unverified sandbox account (sandbox account was created via sandbox.paypal.com flow ) email address to the MTS team for getting that as verified account.